# 音読み for 箱 - word examples

Tags: readings, word-requests, onyomi

I've seen that 箱 could be read as ソウ, but when I look in the dictionaries I use most of the time, I can only find words with はこ （Or ばこ）reading (then you realize that Japanese have boxes for everything ^^)

Do you have any examples where 箱 is read ソウ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have some (from my 漢和辞典):

> 箱櫃{そうき}・箱筥{そうきょ}・箱篋{そうきょう}・箱匣{そうこう}

Every word roughly means "various boxes". None of them is common word, but I can guarantee these words are never read in 訓読み, because it would become はこはこ and you don't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't really any common words using the ソウ reading. However, I was able to find the word 書箱{しょそう}, meaning "bookcase". That word is definitely not common, but it is the only one I can find.

Comment: which can also be read as しょばこ apparently... :(